# Missing namespaces on new Visual Studio extension development installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I need to change an existing Visual Studio 2017 extension development project. This project has everything set up just fine. However in three different computers I tried to install the necessary frameworks to build it as is and in only one of them I actually worked without issues.

I go to my Visual Studio installer and modify it by adding the workload for "Visual Studio extension development", I then open up the project and noticed a bunch of compile errors due to missing namespaces. I thought that maybe the references weren't set up properly so I went looking for what I need to add. However I can't find neither online or by browsing the libraries already in the system the ones I'm supposed to add. Even weirder is that I tried doing this in three different computers an in one of them it worked correctly without ever changing anything.

The following image is just an example of the libraries I'm missing:

[image]

I can't figure out for the life of me what am I missing here, supposedly these should be in the Visual Studio SDK that is installed with Visual Studio installer yet my system can't find it? I tried adding more workloads and components, tried uninstalling and installing again and nothing works and I can't find a single search result with this problem. Why would this work once out of three times with the exact same steps?

Comment: install the nuget packages (like this one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor/15.8.525) 15 = VS2017, 16 = VS2019, so pick correct versions

Comment: thank you a ton, I actually had already tried it before with no success, however this time that one pretty much got rid of almost all library errors because it also imported the correct dependencies, I only had to search for two more and then everything worked correctly, thank you

Answer (score 0):

@magicandre1981 pretty much solved it for me. Installing that microsoft.visualstudio.editor nuget package installed almost all other dependencies as well with only other two missing that I found the reference online.

Since I actually tried it before with no success I now believe the reason that it was not working before was due to not picking the correct version like magicandre mentioned.

Comment: Hi kebrus, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)